# TimePicker without minutes

Tags: android, timepicker

I would like to use a TimePicker view, but only with hours, I don't want to display minutes.
I can't find how to do it !

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NumberPicker` instead:

```
numberPicker.setMinValue(0);
numberPicker.setMaxValue(23);
```